# how to check if Variable is null and set it to zero if it is null

Tags: mysql, null, database-trigger

I have two tables which are Table `Item List` and Table `Rekod` . I try to create a trigger that will update the quantity of a specific item in table `item_list` wherever a record is updated. However I have a problem when entering the very first record. The trigger will not works. It only works when both add and minus record already exist. I try this but seems I can no longer update my `rekod` table as well

````
CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity AFTER UPDATE ON rekod
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE add INT;
    DECLARE minus INT;
    DECLARE final INT;
    SET add = 
SELECT (SELECT SUM(rekod.quantity) from rekod where rekod.status = "add" &&rekod.SKU=item_list.SKU )
FROM item_list ;
    SET minus = 
SELECT (SELECT SUM(rekod.quantity) from rekod where rekod.status = "minus" &&rekod.SKU=item_list.SKU )
FROM item_list ;
    IF add IS NULL
        THEN 
        SET add = 0;
    END IF;
    IF minus IS NULL
        THEN
        SET minus = 0;
    END IF;
    SET final = add - minus;
    UPDATE item_list SET Quantity = final;
END;
//
delimiter ;```
````

Comment: Why do you do this for each row when the trigger body doesn't use row data but seems to update all quantities in itemlist of all items in rekod? If you update 1000 rekod you will run this trigger 1000 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a good reason why all the time list should be synced when an update is made to rekod, such as "when we update rekod we change 10000 rows at a time"

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity AFTER UPDATE ON rekod
BEGIN

    UPDATE 
      item_list
      INNER JOIN (SELECT sku, SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'add' THEN quantity ELSE -quantity END) as s FROM rekod) x
      ON x.sku = item_list.sku
    SET item_list.quantity = x.s;
END;
//
delimiter;
```

Or for keeping itemlist in sync on a row by row basis such as "we only ever update one item at a time in rekod"

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity AFTER UPDATE ON rekod
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE 
      item_list
    SET quantity = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'add' THEN quantity ELSE -quantity END) as s FROM rekod WHERE sku = new.sku) 
    WHERE sku = new.sku;

END;
//
delimiter;
```

Not sure what you're doing about inserts - I'd have thought rekod works like a history table that just has a long sequence of add and minus

Personally I'd just add up rekod every tine I wanted to know the balance rather than try and keep item list in sync

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to test every row the status and determine , if to add or subtract

Like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_quantity AFTER UPDATE ON rekod
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    IF NEW.status = "add"  THEN 
       SET  @add = NEW.quantity;
    ELSE
        SET  @add = - NEW.quantity;
    END IF;

    UPDATE item_list SET Quantity = Quantity + @add WHERE sku = new.sku;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```